# How to build my own Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, android-build

I work on my own android device which has many new APIs (but @hide decorated). My goal is to provide an android sdk to develop on it and use these new APIs.

So my questions is : How to build my own android sdk with these new APIs ?

If the @hide decorated is a problem, i can remove them (I don't have to respect the [CDD](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/fr//compatibility/4.2/android-4.2-cdd.pdf))

Comment: I was under the impression that an SDK came out of a `lunch` build, but I am certainly no expert at that low of a level.

Comment: Thank you, but after my build i dont find any Android.jar. Donc you know where is this expected location ? {$TOP_ANDROID_BUILD}/out/?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this command

```
make -j8 PRODUCT-sdk-sdk showcommands dist
```

here, you can a discussion about it  :
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-building/Y0xduZPWtUs

Comment: Quick note: -j8 refers to the amount of threads make will use when building, you will want it to be -jX where X is the number of logical processors you have

Answer (score 14):

I think the concept of SDK is being misunderstood here.

If you want to release a set of code (API) on top of the Android SDK (Utilities, math libraries, what have you?) just mark your project as a library (Project properties -> Android -> Tick "Is Library") so other Android projects can link to it easily.

Upload the project somewhere like Github and spread the link so others can use it.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, but i wont a library with additionnal code. I have my own device with New APIs to access at some material functions, so i want build my Sdk (Android.jar & co) from my modified Android source code.

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood the question then.